# How do I create Enumerable<Func<>> out of method instances

Tags: c#-4.0, reflection

I am creating a rule set engine that looks kinda like a unit test framework.

```
[RuleSet(ContextA)]
public class RuleSet1
{
    [Rule(TargetingA)]
    public Conclusion Rule1(SubjectA subject)
    { Create conclusion }

    [Rule(TargetingA)]
    public Conclusion Rule2(SubjectA subject)
    { Create conclusion }

    [Rule(TargetingB)]
    public Conclusion Rule3(SubjectB subject)
    { Create conclusion }
}

    [RuleSet(ContextB)]
public class RuleSet2
{
    [Rule(TargetingB)]
    public Conclusion Rule1(SubjectB subject)
    { Create conclusion }

    [Rule(TargetingA)]
    public Conclusion Rule2(SubjectA subject)
    { Create conclusion }

    [Rule(TargetingB)]
    public Conclusion Rule3(SubjectB subject)
    { Create conclusion }
}

public class Conclusion()
{
    // Errorcode, Description and such
}
// contexts and targeting info are enums.
```

The goal is to create an extensible ruleset that doesn't alter the API from consumer POV while having good separation-of-concerns within the code files. Again: like a unit test framework.

I am trying to create a library of these that expose the following API

```
public static class RuleEngine
{
    public static IEnumerable<IRuleSet> RuleSets(contextFlags contexts)
    {
        {
            return from type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                   let attribute =
                       type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (RuleSetAttribute), true)
                           .OfType<RuleSetAttribute>()
                           .FirstOrDefault()
                   where attribute != null
                   select  ?? I don't know how to convert the individual methods to Func's.
        }
    }
}

internal interface IRuleset
{
    IEnumerable<Func<SubjectA, Conclusion>> SubjectARules { get; }
    IEnumerable<Func<SubjectB, Conclusion>> SubjectBRules { get; }
}
```

...which allows consumers to simply use like this (using foreach instead of LINQ for readability in this example)

```
foreach (var ruleset in RuleEgine.RuleSets(context))
{
    foreach (var rule in ruleset.SubjectARules)
    {
        var conclusion = rule(myContextA);
        //handle the conclusion
    }
}
```

Also, it would be very helpful if you could tell me how to get rid of "TargetingA" and "TargetingB" as RuleAttribute parameters and instead use reflection to inspect the parameter type of the decorated method directly. All the while maintaining the same simple external API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Delegate.CreateDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.delegate.createdelegate.aspx) and the [`GetParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getparameters.aspx) method to do what you want.

```
public class RuleSet : IRuleSet
{
    public IEnumerable<Func<SubjectA, Conclusion>> SubjectARules { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Func<SubjectB, Conclusion>> SubjectBRules { get; set; }
}

public static class RuleEngine
{
    public static IEnumerable<IRuleSet> RuleSets() // removed contexts parameter for brevity
    {
        var result = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                     where t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RuleSetAttribute), true).Any()
                     let m = t.GetMethods().Where(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RuleAttribute)).Any()).ToArray()
                     select new RuleSet 
                     {
                        SubjectARules = CreateFuncs<SubjectA>(m).ToList(), 
                        SubjectBRules = CreateFuncs<SubjectB>(m).ToList()
                     };
        return result;
    }
}

// no error checking for brevity
// TODO: use better variable names
public static IEnumerable<Func<T, Conclusion>> CreateFuncs<T>(MethodInfo[] m)
{
    return from x in m 
           where x.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == typeof(T)
           select (Func<T, Conclusion>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, Conclusion>), null, x);
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var sa = new SubjectA();
foreach (var ruleset in RuleEngine.RuleSets())
{
    foreach (var rule in ruleset.SubjectARules)
    {
        var conclusion = rule(sa);
        // do something with conclusion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your LINQ query you headed straight for `RuleSetAttribute`, and so lost other information. If you break the query in several lines of code you can get methods from the type with [`GetMethods()`](http://Type.GetMethods), and then you can call [`GetCustomAttribute<RuleAttribute>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194292.aspx).

Comment: I still can access "type" in my select statement. It's only a "let" statement creating a temporary variable, not a "select" statement which transforms the type. BTW: Shouldn't this be a comment, not an answer?

Comment: I believe I answered the main question, even though I now see that main question is not actually asked. I thought that the main question was how to collect Rule attributes for all methods. Is it not?